# How to Return to a section of a page after form submission

Tags: javascript, html

There is a form on the page that returns to the first page after submission
I want it to stay on this section of the page.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to understand what is "the page" and "this section".

Here are various approaches:

Stay on page:

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); //do stuff if need">
...
</form>
```

Scrolling to a section:

If you have a section `<section id="mySt"></section>`  of either the page of the form or the previous one, you give it an id like i did. To go to it (by scrolling to it), you show that in your URL, for example `http://example.org/#mySt`. That could be in form: `action="somepage.php#mySt"`. Or scripting, you can use `scrollIntoView` on the page you need, when you are deciding it's needed, write in js file:

```
// on some event
var mySt = document.getElementById('mySt');
mySt.scrollIntoView();
```